# jqGrid editGridRow submit button disappears gap between last field and submit

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I am new to jqGrid but I've been working with my solution trying to clean it up and when I edit using EditGridRow it's fine and I can click on submit after making my changes. I can do this a few times for different rows and it seems that each time there's more white space at the bottom of the last field to edit and the submit button until I get to the stage where the submit button is OFF the modal window. I can then click on refresh on the page and now I can see the submit OK. Any ideas as to what is happening an how I can fix (flush out that white space each time). I have tried with taking the default height of auto and setting it specifically to 100% as below and it doesn't seem to make a difference.

```
$("#myDataGrid").jqGrid('editGridRow',gr,{

      reloadAfterSubmit:true,
      closeAfterEdit:true,
      width: 600,
      height: '100%',
...
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's difficult to guess the reason of the problem which can't clear be reproduced. In any way I'd recommend you to add `recreateForm: true` to the list of options of `editGridRow` which you use. If you don't use the option then jqGrid creates Add/Edit form **only once**. If the form will be closed the form will be hidden. On the next call of `editGridRow` the Add/Edit form (previously created) will be visible and its fields will be reinitialized.

If one uses `recreateForm: true` option of `editGridRow` then the previously created Add/Edit form will be always destroyed and recreated instead of making just visible and re-initializing. Probably the usage  of `recreateForm: true` will solve your problem.

Comment: I've had no issues since adding that extra line so I assume that fixed it. Thanks.